# Can't figure out easy limit: $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin(2x^2)}{x^3}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, fractions, limits-without-lhopital

I was trying to help someone with their intro calc homework but got stumped by this super easy problem. I know we can apply L'Hôpital's rule to get $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{4\cos(2x^2)}{3x}$ which goes to $\frac{4}{0}= + \infty$ but I think this doesn't count as a proof. What am I forgetting?

Comment: For small values, the sine is very close to its argument. Hence the limit is virtually that of $2/x$.

Comment: Your method is fine. L'Hospital's Rule is valid if the ratio of derivatives tends to $\pm\infty$ and in that case original limit also tends to $\pm\infty$. But the easiest approach is to use $(\sin x) /x\to 1$ as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the limit as $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{2}{x}\cdot\frac{\sin 2x^2}{2x^2}$$

and, since $$\frac{\sin 2x^2}{2x^2}$$ is bounded and positive, the limit is $\infty$

Comment: The limit of $f'/g'$ does not exist, so that L'Hospital does not apply.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: L'Hospital's Rule does apply in case $f'/g'$ diverges. It fails only if $f'/g'$ oscillates.

Answer (score 1):

You did not forget nothing.  $$(\sin(2x^2))'=4x\cos(2x^2).$$

Note $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{\sin(2x^2)}{2x^2}\cdot\frac{2x^2}{x^3}\right).$$

Thus, our limit it's $+\infty$ for $x\rightarrow0^+$ and it's $-\infty$ for $x\rightarrow0^-$.